# Laravel custom request causing 403 erros

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport, laravel-request, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel Passport in my API project. When I create a custom Request with `php artisan make:request` and use it in a resource controller protected with the middleware `auth:api,` my custom request throws an AuthorizationException and all I can see is 403 Forbidden. When I don't use my custom request, everything is working as expected. I'm using Laravel version 5.8.

Comment: I guess this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008821/laravel-passport-api-status-code403-forbidden

Comment: I do not know how this should solve my problem

Comment: In your custom request file, return true from  authorize() method

Comment: That's working. Thanks!